# Function is not visible inside Function Apps in the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, runtime

I have created a FunctionApp in Azure Portal (Canada central region) and deployed my function from Visual Studio 2019. It published without any error. However, I am not able to see my function inside my FunctionApp in the Azure portal. My Runtime version is ~1 and my code .NET framework is 4.7.2. 
When I change my Runtime version to ~2 or ~3, I am able to see my function inside FunctionApp. I have noticed this issue lately. I have deployed my FunctionApp last month and it was working as expected. I have noticed the above-mentioned issue from last week. 
As part of the investigation, I have deployed my code in the Central US region it is working as expected, but when I deploy the same code in Canada central region, I am not able to see my function under my FunctionApp. 
Does anyone face this issue in any other Azure region? Is it specific to Canada central region?
Thank you!

Comment: In fact, one of my previous function apps in Central US also encountered this problem. In the end, I found that the function app has been successfully deployed, but there is a problem with the ui, it does not show the function, you can check kudu, your function app should have been successfully deployed.

Comment: I noticed a similar issue better raise a support ticket with Microsoft, they can confirm. When I was facing this issue my function was in running state and consuming messages but now showing on UI. I created same function then it came back.

Comment: Any update of this question?

Comment: I have created a ticket with Microsoft and they are working on this issue. I am still facing the same issue in Canada central. When I deployed the same solution in Canada East or Central US everything works as expected. Let's wait for Microsoft to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check again whether the deployment can be successful. Now there is no problem with me in Canada Central.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can't see the function problem on the portal should be related to the recent update to the function portal, and the problem should have be fixed now.